# How to make backspace work on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have recently updated ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04.

Now i observed that `Backspace` is not working for folder(`Up and Back functionality`).

I just found that ubuntu has decided to use `alt + (left right arrows)` for this functionality of moving up and down for folder structure through keyboard

Also to bring back the Backspace feature i found some code

```
gedit .config/nautilus/accels
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")  (Add this line at end)

restart the system
```

I just did exactly as above, but  after restarting i can't able to see the line i added in `accels` file(I think its just not accepting the changes and reloading to original file)

So why is this happening, why the changes are not saving ?

Is there any other way to make the backspace functionality for folder to work in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

The Nautilus acceleration map should be in `.config/nautilus/accels`.

So try `gedit .config/nautilus/accels` to open that file.Then add the lines and restart your pc.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo actually(i typed it manually instead of copy and pasting the path), so actually edited the above file at the path mentioned by you, and can able to write the line in to that file, and after restarting the system when i opened the same file, its asking me to reload the file(which causing to loose the change i did)